# Lightbox behind badge tracker popup may not cover viewport

Tags: bug, design, badge-progress

I'm not sure where to put it, but I found a bug in the layout, probably in the whole Exchange if it uses the same style. Increase the shadow size a little bit maybe?

You can reproduce with making the window size half-width and scroll with the horizontal scrollbar all the way to the right. Then open the badge modalview (that little wheel with the actually tracked badge).

[image]

Comment: I can't repo but I do not have a horizontal scroll bar.  What is your screen resolution?

Comment: 1080p, something smaller in browser, because OS taskbar and window decorations

Comment: Hmm. When I size my window down to when I have a scroll bar it disappears when I click on the badge tracker.  What OS and Browser are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver Chrome, Win8.1. The important part isn't scrolling _after_ opening the modal, but before, when the bar is still visible. Scroll first, open then.

Comment: Aha.  Repo'd.  Win7 with chrome